# R: Dynamically referencing column names when using "$" or "[:]" syntax?

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say in R I have a data frame (called `df`) with a bunch of columns containing integer data named "Var1foo", "Var2foo", and so on.

Now suppose I want to create a new column called `sum1` that adds up everything between "Var3foo" and "Var6foo". I might do:

```
df$sum1 <- rowSums(df[Var3foo:Var6foo])
```

Or, I might do something a bit more complicated and create a new column called `foobar` with `apply()` like so:

```
eenie = 3
meenie = 2
df$foobar <- apply(df, 1, function(x) if (sum(x[Var2foo:Var7foo]) == eenie & sum(x[1:Var3foo]) != meenie) 1 else 0)
```

The problem is I always have to explicitly write out the column names or index when referring to those columns. What if I want to refer to column "Var**x**foo" where `x <- 8` or "Var**y**foo" where `y <- 12`?

What I mean is, I wouldn't be able to do `df$paste0("Var", x, "foo")` or `sum(x[paste0("Var", x, "foo"):paste0("Var", y, "foo")])`.

I also considered using `dplyr::mutate()` to create `df$sum1` and `df$foobar` but it seems to also need explicit column (variable) names.

What should I do? Thanks!!

Comment: Can't use `$` with string column names, but you can use `[`. See the R-FAQ [Dynamically select data frames column names with $](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18222286/903061).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could refer the column with

```
df[paste0("Var", x, "foo")]
```

If you keep using such things a lot, you could use some function to reduce your work,

```
int2name <- function(x, prefix = "", suffix = ""){
    paste0(prefix, x, suffix)
}
```

And then you can use:

```
df[int2name(2:4, prefix = "Var", suffix = "foo")]
```

Comment: Thanks! This might work, but to create a new column without using "$" I only know of `dplyr::mutate()`. However, `mutate()` doesn't seem to like me using `paste0()` to create the new column's name... (`mutate_()` also didn't work) What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: @hpy I think `df[int2name(2:4, prefix = "Var", suffix = "foo")] <- something` can also create new columns, but not as elegant as `mutate`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be directly referencing the columns, with

```
sum(df[,x:y])
```

Of course this only works if the columns are in order.